# No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7,armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

When I use `xcode6.3` and base SDK with IOS8.3 and build my project(old project), then the issue appeared :

> No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7,armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv7
>   armv7s).

Someone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm maybe you are using some library that doesn't support armv7s architecture.

Try to remove armv7s from your project settings.

Comment: but now your project compile if you remove only armv7s? because the error log says that one library is not build for armv7 or armv7s. Which libraries do you use?

Comment: Uhm i don't know why the error occured, but i go to xcode->project->scheme-> edit scheme and don't build test , then it's ok..

Answer (score 1):

Please add below line in because architecture arm64 is missing. Project-> Target -> Architectures -> Architectures. To add basic architectures(armv7, arm64) in your project.

```
$(ARCHS_STANDARD)
```

Comment: i added it, but it did not work, my project contains a static library, when i build the static library, then the issue appeared.. thanks

Comment: The library is build for arm64 ?, Apple reject app that don't support 64 bits